# Gradle Project Dependency

Tags: android, gradle

I have ran into a little problem with very late wanting to move on to gradle with my intellij android project.
Now I have got some trouble with the dependencies. I already know how to add dependencies from given repositories.

I have a whole project in our libs folder, that also is an android project. Now I'm not really sure where/how to put this or whether it is possible to tell gradle that there is a whole project as a dependency. I have to say that the second project is not using any buildscripts so it is not a Gradle-Project.

As for now it is just a directory in our libs folder, and I think it's closer to some kind of sourceSet, but as I'm still new to gradle and I was not lucky finding anything related to my problem I hope you could help me out with a little hint.

Comment: Try turning that project into a jar file and setting it up like any other dependency

Comment: sourceSet makes sense. adding a gradle build file to it would work, too. Or compile it as a jar and include it as such, as suggested by Lukos.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I have rebuilt the project I depend on as a gradle android library module, which now generates an aar file. I have added it as follows in my build.gradle: `dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])
}` But this does not help me, cause the project still cannot resolve the classes I'm using of this library :/